# Error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '' with type 'text/html'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, polymer-1.0, sprockets

i have to used the Polymer-rails gem and when i'am deploying on Heroku said me this error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '' with type 'text/html'

here my output console:

```
    Agencias-iMac-2:coster agencia03$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 537, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (469/469), done.
Writing objects: 100% (509/509), 1.38 MiB | 103 KiB/s, done.
Total 509 (delta 97), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.2
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.3
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.3
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.3
remote:        Using mime-types 2.6.2
remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.3
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.3
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.3
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using railties 4.2.3
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Installing nokogumbo 1.4.5
remote:        Using pg 0.18.3
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.0.3
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Using rails 4.2.3
remote:        Installing polymer-rails 1.1.5
remote:        Installing rails-assets-jquery 2.1.4
remote:        Installing rails-assets-bootstrap 3.3.5
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing responders 2.1.0
remote:        Using sass 3.4.19
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.2
remote:        Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (15.63s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing sprockets (3.4.0)
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '' with type 'text/html'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:88:in `resolve'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:253:in `resolve_with_compat'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:142:in `require_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-rails-1.1.5/lib/polymer-rails/processors/component.rb:24:in `block in require_imports'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-rails-1.1.5/lib/polymer-rails/processors/component.rb:23:in `require_imports'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-rails-1.1.5/lib/polymer-rails/processors/component.rb:16:in `process'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-rails-1.1.5/lib/polymer-rails/processors/sprockets_v3_processor.rb:15:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-rails-1.1.5/lib/polymer-rails/processors/sprockets_v3_processor.rb:10:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:87:in `load_asset_by_uri'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:157:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:87:in `load_asset_by_uri'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:157:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger
remote:        /tmp/build_ddbd90019b1e1d286bbac64c0c08a2a1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to coster.
remote:
```

and here are my gem file:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

gem 'polymer-rails'

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
 gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'
end

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do

  gem 'rails_12factor'

end
```